# How to find average in infopath 2010 with NA Values

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-rules

I have 6 dropdown with the name Checklist1, Checklist2 , Checklist3 etc., with the value from 1 - 10 and NA option

I need to find average of all six column hence my formula was

```
avg(CheckList1 | CheckList2 | CheckList3 | CheckList4 | CheckList5 | CheckList6) / 10
```

which is working fine, only on integres

If i select NA from any one of the drop down box the result is "Nan".

I need to show NA in dropdown as well and avg should come only for non NA columns

How to achieve this any idea

Answer (score 2):

It's not a clean solution but you can try:

Create rule for each drop down that will pass its value to a field. If NA is selected, value should be 0 (zero). So if you have 6 drop downs, you also have 6 fields that will hold these values.